# which to use Cookie or Session? laravel 5.7 - to store data for 5 minutes

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies

guys I'm trying to have 4 steps payment in my application in laravel 5.7

then I wanna store these data in somewhere 4 steps until the payment have been completed and after that I want to store them on database

these 4 steps contains:

1. select product
2. select accessories
3. enter addresses
4. enter payment detail

now please prefer your ways

which to use? **cookie** or **session** or **something else**?

I would use session but I want those data destroyed after 5 minutes and if I choose session lifetime to 5 minutes all of session data will destroy like my login session and I just want destroy the session that I created.

Comment: For this case session

Comment: @Davit bro, i said, I would use session but I want those data destroyed after 5 minutes and if I choose session lifetime to 5 minutes all of session data will destroy like my login session and I just want destroy that session that I created

Comment: you don't need to delete the whole session

Comment: Make additional function to delete session about this after 5 minute

Comment: @B001ᛦ could you help me how can I destroy that specific session after 5 minutes?

Comment: @Davit could you help me how can I destroy that specific session after 5 minutes?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#flash-data

Comment: cache it in a Redis instance with an expiry time against their username/id.  Dont use cookies.  Dont use sessions as youll loose state if they close their browser.

Answer (score 0):

The data you want to store temporarily is a cart quote data in terms of e-commerce. You can store this data in the database, with a timestamp column `expires_at` having value of `current time + 5 minutes`.

Then in your model global scope, which will always filter queries and only get non-expired data :

```
/**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('expires_at', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('expires_at', '<=', Carbon::now());
        });
    }
```

- The advantage of having this is, the data you can used for abandoned cart reports.
- In this data, mostly addresses, products will not contain all details but references using foreign keys to respective tables. If its not the case, I would recommend you to normalise your database.
- Also, if you desire you can delete this data in a weekly cron to
  delete let's say all expired entries of last week.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions provide a way to store information about the user across multiple requests, you should check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session for me is the best option.In the session driver configuration option you can defines where session data will be stored for each request, for example `cookie`, were sessions are stored in secure, encrypted cookies.
Then for your problem about destroy de data you can use the forget method will remove a piece of data from the session. If you would like to remove all data from the session, you may use the flush method.

```
// Forget a single key...
  $request->session()->forget('key');
//or
  $request->session()->flush();
```